how not to reset the naming in the 'file output' node
I have a file output node in the compositor and right now the output format is openEXR. I already setup the names for all the inputs :

Then I change my mind and I want to export as multilayerEXR but as soon as I change the format , all the naming are reset back to default so I have to redo all the renaming from scratch again.

Is this a bug ? is there any setting somewhere to prevent this to happen ?
